# Бесконечный скролл фона

Tags: css

Как можно сделать бесконечный скролл фона при этом не теряя гибкости процентных величин?

Сей блок должен быть 20% высоты от экрана и на разных устройствах будет иметь разный размер. Фон должен под него подстраиваться и быть процентно одинакового размера среди всех устройств.

Я создал это и еще 20 прототипов на которых фон прыгает ибо проценты высчитываются относительно всего блока(так есть ширины экрана), а не размера картинки фона. Вариант с статической величиной (например: `background-size: 300px`) не подходит ибо на телефонах блок будет массивным, может кто посоветует что можно сделать?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body div {
  height: 40%; /*изменил на 40% для сего примера*/
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://st2.depositphotos.com//3547923/7384/v/450/depositphotos_73845815-stock-illustration-cartoon-nature-wild-west-landscape.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: bottom left;
  animation: slide 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    background-position: bottom right;
  }
  100%{
    background-position: bottom left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем если никто не знает варианта получше придется делать через скрипт, а это будет мучительно...

```
  const windowW = window.innerWidth;
  const windowH = window.innerHeight;
  const imageW = 450;
  const imageH = 227;

  const blockH = windowH * 20 / 100;
  const blockW = windowW;

  const newImgH = blockH;
  const newImgW = imageW / (imageH/blockH);

  const newBlockW = (Math.ceil(windowW / newImgW))*newImgW;
```